# How can I only show the table when the filter is complete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, html-table

I got a project in which in which i got some data in format of html table and asked to make a web page where you put in the phone number of a person and when you click the button you will get the result filtered out from the data. You will not be able to see someone's else data without knowing their phone number. I made it till here-

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
</script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search">


<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1239832</td>
    <td>Rhythm</td>
    <td>Class 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2198320</td>
    <td>Rekha</td>
    <td>Class 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21397293</td>
    <td>Arun</td>
    <td>Class 11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You had `</td>` on the headers so I fixed that too

Comment: What is the actual problem? If you want to hide the data, you have to ajax a full number to the server

Comment: _"You will not be able to see someone's else data without knowing their phone number"_ - That's not what your implementation does. An input of `2` would show me everything.

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` on a number is not really useful...

Comment: @Andreas Thats One More issue i just started using java script. I guess i will fix that by using a button or login features afterwards

Comment: I just want that there is a input box you put number in it press a button and data will appear @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simplified version. You need to type or paste the complete number to see the information

Note that this is not safe if you want to hide the information from the user if they do not know the number because they can just look in the source code. If you need a safer lookup, you need to send the number to the server

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr");
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const filter = this.value; 
  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  trs.forEach(tr => tr.hidden = filter && tr.querySelector("td").textContent !== filter)
})
```

```html
</script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr hidden>
      <td>1239832</td>
      <td>Rhythm</td>
      <td>Class 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr hidden>
      <td>2198320</td>
      <td>Rekha</td>
      <td>Class 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr hidden>
      <td>21397293</td>
      <td>Arun</td>
      <td>Class 11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```